# How to remove dart on linux mint

Tags: dart, uninstallation

I have tried to google how to remove darts but found no solution

Does anyone here know how to permanently remove darts?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: i installed it using apt-get

Comment: Then use `apt remove`